# MT4 MQL4- What's the exact timing of an OrderClose()'s result being returned?

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, mt4

I have a question: What's the exact timing of an OrderClose()'s result(true/false) being returned? 
In the following code, will the result of OrderClose() be immediately returned in row1, so we can use it in row2 **within the same tick**?
Or shall we wait for the order being sent to the real market, then the result of filled or not comes back **probably after a few ticks**?

```
...
void OnTick()
{
    bool Order_close_result = false;
    ...
    Order_close_result = OrderClose(..., OrderClosePrice(), ...); //row1, close at market price
    ...
    if(Order_close_result) {...} //row2, to check if it is closed
    ...
}
```

The same confusion comes with OrderModify() too, will the result be returned immediately or after being sent to the real market?

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

After you send trade request in MT4, expert is waiting for a reply. Reply will after some time, let's say 0.5 second. It is possible that new ticks arrive while waiting for a reply from the server. You can use the result instantly. If you wish to try to close again, you have to `RefreshRates()` first, to have the actual price data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!
"You can use the result instantly" →Do you mean I can use the result when the reply comes(for example after 0.5 second)?

Comment: yes, exactly. actually you cannot exit from the function until you receive reply

Comment: So even the code is within "Void OnTick()", if OrderClose() is sent and during the time waiting for its result, we are still staying inside of the function and all new ticks coming will be ignored? (Usually, every new tick triggers a new OnTick() run if not trapped).
Is my understanding correct?

Comment: yes. `OnTick()` is ignored if previous is still in process (either trade functions, or time consuming functions, doesnt matter).